# Visual Basic Using DateTimePicker to determine dates for SQL Query

Tags: sql, vba, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use a datetimepicker to determine the dates for an SQL Query and am having a hard time getting the query to run.  Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim date1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    Dim date2 As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    myLowerDate = "'" + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(date1, 19) + "'"
    myUpperDate = "'" + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(date2, 19) + "'"


Dim Query1 As String =
"SELECT DISTINCT 
'''' + d.ID + '''' AS DeliveryID,
l.Name AS LocationName

FROM 
Locations l JOIN Deliveries d
ON l.id = d.LocationID

JOIN DeliveryRecords dr 
ON d.ID = dr.DeliveryID

JOIN Items i 
ON dr.ItemID = i.ID
    WHERE 
        (l.OwnerUserID = 'aaaaa' OR l.OwnerUserID = 'bbbbb') AND
        l.Deleted is NULL AND
        ISNUMERIC(l.CustomID) = 1 AND
        dr.Created <= DATEADD(HOUR, 8, " + myUpperDate + ") AND 
        dr.Created >= DATEADD(HOUR, 8, " + myLowerDate + ")"

SQLCon.Open()

    Try

        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query1, SQLCon)

        Dim R As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While R.Read

            xName = R("Name").ToString
            xDate = R("Date").ToString
            xDueDate = R("DueDate").ToString
            xInvoiceNumber = R("InvoiceNumber").ToString

        End While

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

When I run this, I get an error due to my SQL query, but when I replace my variables with actual values, it runs fine.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You store your dates as text which obviously gives you error when you try to use it as date. Try debugging your code and see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong.  I ended up setting my query as a function with with dates as variables and plugging that into my run query sub.